# Subject pronoun vs object pronoun

Tags: grammar, adjectives, clauses

What is the main difference between adjective clause with subject pronoun and object pronoun?

Comment: Please provide examples of what you think an "adjective clause", a "subject pronoun" and an "object pronoun" are.

Answer (score 3):

The OP didn't give any information, so I will answer one question that might occur to someone:

> What is the main difference between a restrictive relative clause with a **subject** relative pronoun  and a restrictive relative clause with an **object** relative pronoun?
>
> For example,
>
> - *That's the man **who/that** saw her.* (**the man** saw her: subject)
> - *That's the man (**who/that**) she saw*. (she saw **the man**: object)

Well, the main difference is that when the relative pronoun is the object, you can delete the relative pronoun (that's what the parentheses around them means), because the sentence already has a subject, and you don't need to go to the trouble of putting the pronoun up front to mark it as a relative clause.

- *That's the man she saw*

That's grammatical because two noun phrases in a row like *the man she* is a mark of a relative clause and causes our parser to push down one level and start parsing a subordinate clause. If all you hear is

- *I like the man she ...*

you're gonna understand that the next thing is a verb and *she* is its subject, so you can afford to leave out *which* or *that* here, and still be understood and colloquial.

However, that's **not** the case with relative pronouns that are subjects. Relative clauses are tensed, and every English tensed clause has to have a subject (or, in an emergency, something resembling a subject, like *there* or *it*). If you deleted the relative pronoun in the first example, you'd get an ungrammatical sentence

- **That's the man saw her.*

I can't think of any other real difference.